# How to use different colors.scss file in React.js

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I have a React.js project with different scss files for colors, fonts which is imported into app.scss like the below structure

[image]

And in app.scss it has been imported like this

```
@charset "utf-8";
@import 'settings/settings';
@import 'tools/tools';
@import 'generic/generic';

// Imports fonts separately because of issues with Storybook and loading fonts from here
@import 'generic/fonts';
@import 'generic/fonts-arabic';
@import 'generic/fonts-armenian';
@import 'utilities/utilities';
```

And this app.scss file has been imported in the Layout.tsx file which works fine and it renders the color which has been provided and the fonts which has been added is getting rendered properly.

Now i would like to create a theme in the same codebase with different colors and fonts by not affecting the components which have been created.

I would like to switch the theme (Which will have different color sets and fonts) on a button click.

My question is it possible to create another set of .scss files for colors and fonts and import the necessary scss file based on a condition?